# Chrome cannot get the width and height from an image created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

My web application has many image presentation features, and most of time we need to resize them. I attempted to get its real width and height values by the following fragment code:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = IMAGE_URL;

var width = image.width;
var height = image.height;
```

The above code runs no problem on browsers like Firefox and IE 10, but it returns 0 on Chrome. I guess Chrome doesn't support this.

Can anybody gives me guidance on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to get width and height **after** the image loads and understands what its made of.

try:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    var width = image.width;
    var height = image.height;
}
image.src = IMAGE_URL;
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    width = this.width;
    height = this.height;
};
```

Onload help you to get width and height.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the `load` event, otherwise the dimensions of the image won't be known.

```
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    var width = image.width;
    var height = image.height;
    // These values will now be correct.
};

image.src = IMAGE_URL;
```